# Windows console subsystem default font size bigger than "Default"

Tags: fonts

On a 3200x1600 Windows 10 laptop screen, the largest 20x10 listed on the default tab is too small.  Is there a HKCU/Console setting or other permanent method to get all of the console system based windows to use a larger font?  The properties allows a 36 high font size on a current window basis only.